# How many Probability Models are there?

Tags: probability

How many different kinds of Probability Distribution Models are there ?.. Incuding the commonly used ones.. and all other possible types ?

Comment: Infinitely many.  I suspect this answer--which is perfectly correct (and I hope is perfectly obvious)--is also of no use to you.  What is the actual statistical problem you want to address?

Comment: I am interested in knowing the range of models a typical Data Scientist or a Quant may be using ?.. Or may be helpful in financial modelling ?

Comment: You might want to choose between the two "Data Scientist" or "Quant". Also other ways of making it more specific will be necessary for you to get a better answer. Do you want to become a Data Scientist or a "Quant"? What type of data are you interested in? (Biological, financial, sociological, etc.) Are you looking for a reference which will introduce you to distributions relevant to a specific field of interest? Or do you want a list? Wikipedia has one already: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions -- it's technically not comprehensive, but that would be impossible.

Comment: I don't think it's silly to want to know the scope of a field like data science--but it's so broad, varied, and flexible (people can invent a new model for each new problem they encounter) that I don't think we could provide an adequate answer within the framework of this site.

Comment: Hi !..Chill2Macht.. I'm specifically thinking about the financial market modelling problem..

Comment: I was wondering what resources..are actually used in financial modelling in real life scenarios.. How much of statistical theory or what softwares are used.

Comment: This is still too broad .. .and now starts to be rather more opinion-based as well. You'll need to edit your question to be specific, clear and supportable with citeable sources or demonstrable facts

Answer (score 2):

Like @whuber says, there are infinitely many. To see this, consider modeling a random variable as normally distributed with unknown mean $θ$ and some fixed standard deviation, say 1. You can choose any positive real number for the standard deviation, each of which results in a distinct model, so not only are there infinitely many models, this narrow class of models contains [uncountably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) many models.

Comment: I realize that.. my question ia very vague and non technical.. But the field is so hush hush..and full of jargons.. It's hard for me to be precise.

Comment: @Kriss the difficulty for you of being precise is no doubt a real difficulty, but doesn't make your present question suitable for our site. Please take a look at [what kinds of posts are on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), some [types of questions to avoid](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), plus [how to ask a good question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what to do with a question that's on hold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  The fact that in comment your question seems to shift ground to a quite different issue each time someone responds to you suggests you need to think very carefully about what you really want to find out, and you should begin with a solid attempt to research that more specific question first, then come back and ask a fresh question (which should include a clear description of what you did in your attempt to research it and what you were able to find out)

Comment: @Kriss "Hush-hush"? There's nothing secret about statistics. All the important stuff is published in textbooks, journal articles, and conference presentations.